# Generic solution for setting uniform parameters in openGL (C#)

Tags: c#, opengl, generics, opentk

I would like to have a generic solution for adding parameters to shaders via openTK. OpenTK offers implementations for different types of parameters (float, int, double...) via `SetUniform()`. Now in my program I would like to do something like `ShaderParam<T>(string name, params T[] values)`. Unfortunately I have two problems with this. I see no good solution to store objects of ShaderParam and I'm not sure what's the most elegant solution to translate this to the openTK interface. I don't like to do a `switch(typeof(T))`, is there a more generic way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL specification provides [different functions](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) for each uniform type: `glUniform[1234][fui][v]`. In practical terms, this means that the `switch(typeof(T))` is mandated by the fundamental design of OpenGL.

All is not lost, however! OpenGL 3.1 and higher include [Uniform Buffer Objects](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object) that allow you to upload uniforms using `GL.BufferData<T>` or `GL.MapBuffer`. If you can live with the requirement of OpenGL 3.1+, UBOs lead to cleaner and faster code.

Comment: [overloading, what it means exactely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading), mandated by the common sens

Comment: where have you seen reference to generic type in my answer? where have you seen <T>??

Comment: I am trying to answer the original question, which explicitly mentions generics: `I would like to have a generic solution for adding parameters to shaders via openTK`. Please be constructive and try to stay on topic.

Comment: Ok, I was maybe a bit aggaced, sorry. But be constructive too, and replace `overloads`by functions.

Answer (score -1):

OpenTK api wrap OpenGL api in c  that does not handle overloading. [The wrapping is automated](http://www.opentk.com/node/3269) and for now, it strip OpenGLTypes and create overloads.

*Edit: (specialy for fidler)*

Overloading is achieve declaring same function name pointing to different entry point, exemple:

```
[AutoGenerated(Category = "ARB_shader_objects", Version = "", EntryPoint = "glUniform1ivARB")]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static void Uniform1(Int32 location, Int32 count, Int32[] value);

[AutoGenerated(Category = "ARB_shader_objects", Version = "", EntryPoint = "glUniform1fvARB")]
[CLSCompliant(false)]
public static unsafe void Uniform1(Int32 location, Int32 count, Single* value);
```

The most elegant way would be to [hack directly OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/doc/hacking/wrapper-design) and improve the wrapper generator, stripping the array and matrix qualifier of the uniform functions.

Comment: @The Fiddler: I've not mention generic type, I'm talking about extending actual gl functions overloading, which is limited to gl types stripping]. [where to start, line 43...](https://github.com/andykorth/opentk/blob/master/Source/Bind/FuncProcessor.cs)

Comment: The original question explicitly asks about generics, not overloading: `ShaderParam<T>(string name, params T[] values)`. The only way to upload uniforms via generics is UBOs - no amount of overloading will change that fact.